# LINQ Grouping by Sum Value

Tags: c#, linq

Say I have a class like so:

```
public class Work
{
    public string Name;
    public double Time;

    public Work(string name, double time)
    {
        Name = name;
        Time = time;
    }
 }
```

And I have a `List<Work>` with about 20 values that are all filled in:

```
List<Work> workToDo = new List<Work>();
// Populate workToDo
```

Is there any possible way that I can group `workToDo` into segments where each segments sum of Time is a particular value? Say `workToDo` has values like so:

```
Name | Time
A    | 3.50
B    | 2.75
C    | 4.25
D    | 2.50
E    | 5.25
F    | 3.75
```

If I want the sum of times to be 7, each segment or `List<Work>` should have a bunch of values where the sum of all the Times is 7 or close to it. Is this even remotely possible or is it just a stupid question/idea? I am using this code to separate `workToDo` into segments of 4:

```
var query = workToDo.Select(x => x.Time)
        .Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x})
        .GroupBy(y => y.Index / 4)
        .ToList();
```

But I am not sure how to do it based on the Times.

Comment: It is possible, but you'll have to be more specific about how you want things grouped.  How close to 7 must the sums be?  Can we just keep including items in a segment until it goes over 7?  Do the elements in a segment have to be contiguous?

Comment: Are you wanting it to group by `Name` still, but repeat the name in order to make sure that each result is 7 or less?

Comment: Or are you trying to make a list like: `{ A + B, C + D, E, F }`?

Comment: @RiskyMartin Hopefully you could specify or change a variable that will determine how far away the items can be to 7. I guess you could keep including items until it goes within the boundaries (between 6 and 8 for the 7 example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution recurses through all combinations and returns the ones whose sums are close enough to the target sum.

Here is the pretty front-end method that lets you specify the list of work, the target sum, and how close the sums must be:

```
public List<List<Work>> GetCombinations(List<Work> workList,
                                        double targetSum,
                                        double threshhold)
{
    return GetCombinations(0,
                           new List<Work>(),
                           workList,
                           targetSum - threshhold,
                           targetSum + threshhold);
}
```

Here is the recursive method that does all of the work:

```
private List<List<Work>> GetCombinations(double currentSum,
                                         List<Work> currentWorks,
                                         List<Work> remainingWorks,
                                         double minSum,
                                         double maxSum)
{
    // Filter out the works that would go over the maxSum.
    var newRemainingWorks = remainingWorks.Where(x => currentSum + x.Time <= maxSum)
                                          .ToList();
    // Create the possible combinations by adding each newRemainingWork to the 
    // list of current works.
    var sums = newRemainingWorks
                   .Select(x => new
                          {
                              Works = currentWorks.Concat(new [] { x }).ToList(),
                              Sum = currentSum + x.Time
                          })                                
                   .ToList();
    // The initial combinations are the possible combinations that are
    // within the sum range.                   
    var combinations = sums.Where(x => x.Sum >= minSum).Select(x => x.Works);
    // The additional combinations get determined in the recursive call.
    var newCombinations = from index in Enumerable.Range(0, sums.Count)
                          from combo in GetCombinations
                                        (
                                            sums[index].Sum,
                                            sums[index].Works,
                                            newRemainingWorks.Skip(index + 1).ToList(),
                                            minSum,
                                            maxSum
                                        )
                          select combo;
    return combinations.Concat(newCombinations).ToList();        
}
```

This line will get combinations that sum to 7 +/- 1:

```
GetCombinations(workToDo, 7, 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a query that segments your data in groups where the times are near to 7, but not over:

```
Func<List<Work>,int,int,double> sumOfRange = (list, start, end) => list
                  .Skip(start)
                  .TakeWhile ((x, index) => index <= end)
                  .ToList()
                  .Sum (l => l.Time);

double segmentSize = 7;
var result = Enumerable.Range(0, workToDo.Count ())
    .Select (index => workToDo
                         .Skip(index)
                         .TakeWhile ((x,i) => sumOfRange(workToDo, index, i) 
                                              <= segmentSize));
```

The output for your example data set is:

```
A 3.5
B 2.75
total: 6.25

B 2.75
C 4.25
total: 7

C 4.25
D 2.5
total: 6.75

D 2.5
total: 2.5

E 5.25
total: 5.25

F 3.75
total: 3.75
```

If you want to allow a segments to total over seven, then you could increase the `segmentSize` variable by 25% or so (i.e. make it 8.75).

Comment: Also, Is there a way to have the results not one after each other? For example one output could be `D 2.5 and F 3.75 for a total of 6.25`.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is a [packing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problem) (where the tasks are being packed into 7-hour containers). Whilst it would be possible to use LINQ syntax in a solution to this problem, there is no solution inherent in LINQ that I am aware of.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I had no idea that this problem had a name.